# Javascript reduce a number by a percentage within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a third-party estimation tool that is consistently providing results 30% higher than it should, and getting the company to update the tool isn't an option. So, how can I use Javascript/jQuery DOM to adjust the numbers being rendered?

```
<div class="general-avg"><strong>$276,000</strong></div>
```

I would like to capture the $276,000 as a variable and then reduce it by 30%. Can anyone explain how to do this? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually SO community expects at least some code that you might have tried to solve the issue yourself. That is most likely the reason for all the down votes.

But I will assume that JS is not your main job and you don't even know where to start so I will help you out.

This solution does not need any library, it works without jQuery.

```
// first lets get the divs by class name
var values = document.getElementsByClassName('general-avg');

// then lets go through each of the divs and select strong element inside
[].forEach.call(values, function (item) {
  // assumption is that your 3rd party gives you always just one strong tag inside
  var strong       = item.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0];
  // once we have that element selected, take the number from inside, strip $ and remove commas, parse it to float
  var newValue     = parseFloat(strong.innerText.replace('$','').replace(',',''));

  // once we have that, multiply by 0.7 (I sure hope that is how you deduct 30%, otherwise this is emberassing)
  newValue = newValue * 0.7;

  // once we have that value we just need to format it a bit, this is shameless copy paste from
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899795/3963682
  var formatNewValue = newValue.toString().split(".");
  newValue = formatNewValue[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (formatNewValue[1] ? "." + formatNewValue[1] : "");

  // at the end, put the number back in, and add $ sign in front
  strong.innerText = '$' + newValue;
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgeQjV

Comment: Thank you. I greatly appreciate it. You're right, JS isn't my main job... mostly just design and some UI stuff. Again, thanks... this helped alot.

Comment: Miroslav, how would I round to the nearest integer with this? I tried strong.innerText = '$' + Math.round(Number(newValue)); on the last line, but that's not working for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! :)
added "newValue = Math.round(newValue);" right after "newValue = newValue * 0.7;"

Comment: But depending on what the app does, be careful about rounding. You can check here  about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round . Also maybe worth looking into `ceil` or `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

Attached below is some javascript that will run on page load and will reduce any tag with the classname `general-avg` by 30 percent

```
var Numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("general-avg");
for (var i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
  Numbers[i].innerText = "$" + Math.round(Number(Numbers[i].innerText.replace(/\D/g, '')) * 0.7).toString().replace(/(...)(.)/g, "$1,$2")
}
```

A demo of the code can be found: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/btvLnqyt/5/)

Comment: breaks completely on numbers which are don't produce round result: https://jsfiddle.net/btvLnqyt/4/

Comment: Miroslav i have fixed it so that it rounds up to a whole number: jsfiddle.net/btvLnqyt/5

Comment: OP hasn't specified what happens in that case, you can't just round up financial numbers

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.general-avg strong').each(function() {
  var $avgPrice = $(this)
  var number = Number($avgPrice[0].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
  
  // the 1000s avoid rounding issues
  number = number - (number * 0.3 * 1000 / 1000)
  
  $avgPrice[0].innerHTML = `$${numberWithCommas(number)}`
})

//put the commas back in
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="general-avg"><strong>$100,000</strong></div>
<div class="general-avg"><strong>$276,000</strong></div>
```

`numberWithCommas` function [came from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)